# How were values of Vc(0+) and i(1.5ms) found?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-analysis, capacitance

I get that by applying source transformation, we get a (0.1*200=20 V) source but shouldn't 0.1 A current be divided into 50 ohm and 100 ohm resistance?
Also why i=0 at t=1.5ms?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to remember is that it is not just a 20V ideal source.

The Norton-Thevenin equivalency converts a current source with a parallel resistor into a voltage source **with a series resistor**. So your 0.1A current source and 200Ω parallel resistor transforms into a 20V ideal voltage source with a 200Ω series resistor.

When delivering current through the 50Ω resistor (when the capacitor is not yet fully charged), you have a potential divider, so the output voltage of your non-ideal source will be less than 20V. This is exactly the same as the current source output being split between the 200Ω and 50Ω parallel resistances in the non transformed circuit.

Comment: Why did we use 50 ohms  resistance in time constant, and not 200 ohm?

Comment: Also why i=0 at t=1.5ms?

Comment: @Maya: because the 200 ohm resistor was shorted to ground by the switch at t=0. Also, i can't equal zero at 1.5ms, so that's an error.

Comment: Can i also say that since capacitor eventually begins an open circuit so no current flows and i=0?

Comment: @Maya: You can say it, but it won't be true since charge flows into it when it's charging and out of it when it's discharging.

Answer (score 1):

When the switch is open, the capacitor will charge to whatever voltage appears across the 200 ohm resistor.

Once the capacitor charges, all the current from the 100mA source will go through the 200 ohm resistor, and the voltage that'll appear across the resistor will be:

$$ E= IR =0.1A \times 200\Omega = 20 \text{volts}$$

Then, when the switch closes, the 100mA from the current source will be shunted to ground through the switch as will the current from the cap as it discharges through 50 ohms to ground, the 200 ohm resistor being shunted by the switch.